# Set-up blog on Github pages

Tags: github, blogs, jekyll, github-pages

I have a Github pages site already up and running at **http://pshrishi.github.io**, where I have my resume posted at **pshrishi.github.io/resume** and a couple of other presentations at similar URLs/addresses like **pshrishi.github.io/XYZ**. I would like to host a blog at a URL like **pshrishi.github.io/blog**.

I have jekyll set-up on my MBP, and have been looking for a step-by step guide to go ahead with the blog. Any help would be appreciated, since I'd like the blog to go live as soon as possible.

I've listed the steps that I've tried so far, below:

- `cd pshrishi.github.io`
- Create a new jekyll project : `jekyll new blog`
- Update the `_config.yml` file.
- `cd blog`, and `jekyll serve`
- The blog works just fine when I access it on my localhost at `localhost:4000`

Answer (score 2):

Your jekyll is not at the top level of the repo. Github is not able to read it.

Simply move your jekyll out from /blog onto the root directory of this repo.

**Added:**

Your current wrong setup is like the following:

```
/pshrishi.github.io
      /blog
          /<jekyll-content> 
          /index.html
          /_posts
          /_config.yml
          /blah-blah
      /resume
          /<jekyll-content-again> 
          /index.html
          /_posts
          /_config.yml
          /blah-blah
```

You should make the jekyll this way:

```
/pshrishi.github.io
    /<jekyll-content> 
    /index.html
    /_posts
    /_config.yml
    /blah-blah
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't really need jekyll for the other pages. My current directory structure is something like:

    /pshrishi.github.io
      /resume
        index.html
        /css
        /js
      /factory
        index.html
        /css
        /js
      /blog
        /jekyll_stuff

What should I do to get the following results?
- Open pshrishi.github.io/resume to view my resume
- Open pshrishi.github.io/XYZ to view any other pages I might add in the future.
- Open pshrishi.github.io/blog to view my `jekyll-based-blog`.

Answer (score 2):

As @ytbryan says, if your jekyll site is not at the root, it will not be generated by Github pages.

Two solutions :

#### 1 - in your user repository **pshrishi.github.io**

- put everything at the root
- in _setting.yml, set `permalink: /blog/:month-:day-:year/:title.html`. this will generate your posts in `/blog` folder
- put a link to your resume and other pages on the index page.

#### 2 - in a **blog** repository

Just put your blog files in a `gh-pages` and all your Jekyll site will be accessible at `pshrishi.github.io/blog`

Answer (score 0):

A good solution to use such "sub-domains" through `github` would be to first create an `organization` in your name (e.g. pshrishi_organization). Then, you create your website/blog/resume as respective repositories in this organization (e.g. called `blog`). The `github.io` address pointing to the root of your `blog.git` repository will now be: [pshrishi_organization.github.io/blog](http://pshrishi_organization.github.io/blog)

The disadvantage of this approach is that you won't be able to use the root address available ([pshrishi_organization.github.io](http://pshrishi_organization.github.io)) - at least I could not figure out how to do that, yet.